# Writing bytes to file from multiple packets

Tags: java, sockets, networking, file-writing

i am working on algorithm that will receive data and i want to write them to the file.
First packet that i receive is packet containing fileName.
Second packet is containing sizeOfPacket.
then i have to calculate number of Packets that i receive.
But my actual problem starts when i want to receive next packets and write these packets to the file byte by byte.
I tried it in many ways but every time the resulting file is just 1kb large but actual image is 72kb large.
I have to read from the packets from 4th byte because first 4 bytes are storing position of packet in file.

Size of every packet is 1024B

```
public void run(int port) throws IOException {    
      try {
            byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
            DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(port);

            System.out.printf("Listening on udp:%s:%d%n",
            InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress(), port);     
            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(
                               receiveData,
                               SIZE_OF_PACKET
                               );

            //first packet with name of file
            serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            String fileName = utils.getFileName(receivePacket);

            //System.out.println(fileName);
            //System.out.println(fileName.length());

            //second packet with size of whole data()
            serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            int sizeOfFile = utils.BytesToInt(receivePacket);

            //get number of packets that are needed
            int numOfPackets = utils.getNumOfPackets(sizeOfFile);
            //System.out.println(sizeOfFile);
            //System.out.println(numOfPackets);

            //output stream for file "test.jpg"
              FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.jpg");
              //loop over for the number of Packets
              for(int i = 0; i < numOfPackets - 1; i++) {
                  serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
                  receiveData = receivePacket.getData();
                  //byte byte after byte and write it to the file
                  // start at index 3 bcs first byte is packet number
                  for(int a = 3; a < SIZE_OF_PACKET - 1;a++) {
                      Byte nextByte = receiveData[a];
                      if(nextByte != 0) fos.write(nextByte);

                  }

              }
              fos.close();
              serverSocket.close();

      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What is the value of `SIZE_OF_PACKET`?

Comment: Why are you stripping out the `0` bytes. How are you ensuring every file is an exact multiple of `SIZE_OF_PACKET` What if the file is a different size?

Comment: it s predefined that packet will be of size 1024